# Basic python script giving Internal Server Error

Tags: python

I'm using hostgator and they swear that python is supported, but I've yet to see one working python script. I've tried several scripts, my latest one is the one they give on their website:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head>";
print "<title>CGI Test</title>";
print "</head><body>";
print "<p>Test page using Python</p>";
print "</body></html>";
```

I'm getting an Internal Server Error:
http://elkuzu.com/cgi-bin/test.py

The file has 755 permissions, so does the folder cgi-bin. They refused to help me with what they call "coding" problems... but with all that I've tried and received nothing but Internal Server Errors, I'm thinking the problem is with them. Anyone know what could be wrong?

Error Logs:

```
[Sat May 19 09:11:38 2012] [error] [client 74.129.48.242] File does not exist: /home/elkuzu/public_html/404.shtml
[Sat May 19 09:11:38 2012] [error] [client 74.129.48.242] File does not exist: /home/elkuzu/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sat May 19 09:11:37 2012] [error] [client 74.129.48.242] File does not exist: /home/elkuzu/public_html/500.shtml
```

I've talked with my host (hostgator) and they've turned it into a ticket, which makes me think that something is up on their end.

Comment: I couldn't seem to find the logs, where can i go to see them? cpanel?

Comment: Yes, cpanel look for Apache Error logs.

Comment: [Sat May 19 09:11:38 2012] [error] [client 74.129.48.242] File does not exist: /home/elkuzu/public_html/404.shtml
[Sat May 19 09:11:38 2012] [error] [client 74.129.48.242] File does not exist: /home/elkuzu/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sat May 19 09:11:37 2012] [error] [client 74.129.48.242] File does not exist: /home/elkuzu/public_html/500.shtml

Comment: Have you tried putting test.py in a different directory? These error messages are just when apache looks for the pages to handle 404 and 500 error requests, and the [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

Comment: I've put it in the root folder, which caused it to show up as a text file. Then I changed the .htaccess to run the scripts and then it gave a Internal Server Error for the script.

Comment: Ahh what python version? Python 3+ changed print to be a function - try `print ("test")`

Comment: It's supposedly Python 2 according to the hostgator site.

Comment: All sorted? What was the problem?

Comment: They said that the files were saved as like dos or something and needed to be saved as unix. I figured out how to do it within notepad++. Unfortunately that was something I've never had to do before so I had no idea what that meant when everyone was saying to make sure to use unix.

Comment: I've updated my question as a reference for the future :)

Comment: What was the resolution to this problem? I see that you mark one of the answer as the right answer, but at the same time you stated that it wasn't working.

Comment: Sorry it was so long ago I don't remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html) on how to use Python as a CGI.

In your case, the issue was the line endings. They're the hidden character at the end of each line.

> On a Unix-like system, The line endings in the program file must be
>   Unix style line endings. This is important because the web server
>   checks the first line of the script (called shebang) and tries to run
>   the program specified there. It gets easily confused by Windows line
>   endings (Carriage Return & Line Feed, also called CRLF), so you have
>   to convert the file to Unix line endings (only Line Feed, LF). This
>   can be done automatically by uploading the file via FTP in text mode
>   instead of binary mode, but the preferred way is just telling your
>   editor to save the files with Unix line endings. Most editors support
>   this.

On Windows (ie Notepad) they're represented as  (CR LF, or `\r\n`), whereas on unix they're  (LF or `\n`).

In [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), you can view line endings as symbols like so: View -> Show Symbol -> Show End of Line

To replace windows linebreaks with unix ones, you can use: Search -> Replace...

In the replace dialogue, find `\r\n`, and replace them with `\n`. Ensure the Extended Search mode is selected.

[image: Notepad++ replace dialogue screenshot]

---

Alternatively, you can use Edit -> EOL Conversion -> UNIX Format

[image: Notepad++ EOL Conversion screenshot]

Comment: I tried the .htaccess and that seemed to just allow me to run .py from the root folder, but it still showed up with an internal server error. I tried adding an extra enter at the bottom of the test.py script but nothing changed.

Comment: @Tyler I've updated my answer - can you try that script? It'll tell you the python version. You shouldn't need any semicolons

Comment: Same Internal Server Error, and same error in the error logs: http://elkuzu.com/cgi-bin/python3.py

Comment: What type of line endings are you using? See the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html) - "On a Unix-like system, The line endings in the program file must be Unix style line endings"

Comment: I'm just using the ; line endings as shown in my code above. I'm reading that link you gave me. I think the server is a Linux server... so I'm trying some of the stuff.

Comment: Changing Encoding using EOL conversion worked for Godaddy Host Account

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was running into 500 error with hostgator as well (to point that I quit trying a year ago). A few days ago a decided to try it again following their "[tutorial](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/perl-and-python-scripts)" and it again it didn't work.

I try something simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print sys.version_info
```

I got 500 error again, However after chatting with support they gave a log message
saying:

> [error] [client 192.x.x.x] malformed header from script. Bad header=(2, 6, 6, 'final', 0): test1.py

With that information (the log message contained the python so in some way it was executing) I found this post in the [Unix site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123866/500internal-server-error-from-cgi-program), where I got this:

> As the HTTP spec (and the error message from your HTTP server) specify, you need one blank line between the HTTP headers and the body, otherwise the server doesn't know where the headers end and the body begins.

I changed my script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print ""
import sys
print sys.version_info
```

And it worked!. Oddly enough, after running this script successfully, the example in the tutorial (code below) is now working for me as well

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head>";
print "<title>CGI Test</title>";
print "</head><body>";
print "<p>Test page using Python</p>";
print "</body></html>";
```

Why it works now? I have no clue, but at least I hope this answer help somebody dealing with hostgator [lack of] support.